# SimpleInjector MVC package and Web API

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, simple-injector

For a Web API project, is the SimpleInjector MVC package the one to use?

[Here is a link](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SimpleInjector.Integration.AspNetCore.Mvc).

Comment: No, use [SimpleInjector.Integration.WebApi
] (https://www.nuget.org/packages/SimpleInjector.Integration.WebApi/)

Comment: Please read the [Web API Integration Guide](https://simpleinjector.org/webapi). If, after reading that, and trying it out, any questions remain, please update or rephrase your question.

Comment: Thanks qujck.  That helped.  @Steven - truthfully I didn't go through it in detail, but it refers to applications having a global.asax rather than a Startup.cs.  Seems like maybe you should do some document reading.  ;)

Comment: Startup? This implies you want to build an ASP.NET Core application. In ASP.NET Core, the distinction between MVC and Web API has been removed, which means you have one unified model. See [the ASP.NET Core integration guide](https://simpleinjector.org/aspnetcore) for more details.

Comment: @Steven:  Thank you very much for that clarification!!!

Comment: @Steven - just to clarify: Even though I'm making an API, I should still use the SimpleInjector.Integration.AspNetCore.Mvc nuget package?

Comment: That is correct.